# SQL Server In Memory Tables performance for autocomplete search performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, redis

I am using SQL Server and sometimes the performance of it is not enough.

**I just want to know if MS SQL Server could handle searches on tables with a couple millions of rows with a good performance (below 1 sec).**

For example, I need to do an autocomplete search that should work fluently and fastly so that the user will have a good user experience. In order to do it, I need to have a fast query mechanism. I am not sure that with SQL Server it will have a great performance.

I know that there are In Memory tables which improve the performance, but would it be enough?

I also thought to use `Redis` as the search engine which I know is really fast, but then it means that I will have to have 2 databases (SQL Server and Redis) and I want to avoid it if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Test to confirm that you have a problem before trying to solve the problem? A lookup that just uses a trailing wildcard can be indexed, in general/simple use cases personally I would not expect any problems.

Comment: @AlexK.This is not that easy to test as you think.
This is a big project with lots of tables and to create something similar to this and doing loads on the test site would take lots of time. To save this time I am doing an investigation and in addition to my investigation, I wrote here the question with a hope to get an answer from experienced people who used SQL Server to do this.
Sometimes answers of experienced people could be quite good and helpful and save hundreds of hours.

Comment: @AlexK.About your offer to index... I know it could be index and it would be good for simple, not big use cases.
But when you have millions of rows, it is possible that the index would not be enough and the search would not work fluently.